# Remove duplicated objects in JavaScript Array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

First of, I am aware that there are LOTS of answers on SO on this, but I am having some issues with them, that is why I post another question on this topic.

So here is my Array of Objects:

```
0: {id: 'lAYOUT', label: 'lAYOUT', items: 'val1'}
1: {id: 'tecst', label: 'tecst', items: 'val1'}
2: {id: 'tecst', label: 'tecst', items: 'val1'}
```

I am trying to filter out that there would be only 2 values, since there are 2 objects in array that are the same. I would like to make unique objects by `items` and `label`.

This is how I am trying to do it with `lodash`:

```
const filteredArray = uniq(nestedItems, (item, key, a) => item.items && item.label)
```

But it keeps returning me all 3 elements still.

I also tried it like this:

```
const filteredArray = [...new Set(nestedItems)]
```

Comment: What is the `key` in array ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: @MayurVaghasiya My bad, I copied/paste wrong. Instead of `key` it should be `label`, but issue exist, I just copied it on SO wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) get the particular object `value, index and array`.
Using [FindIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) get the particular array object. and compare `filter object` and `findindex object`, if it return false then push in new array! and make new unique array !

Try this code !

```
 let arr = [{ id: 'lAYOUT', label: 'lAYOUT', items: 'val1' },
    { id: 'tecst', label: 'tecst', items: 'val1' },
    { id: 'tecst', label: 'tecst', items: 'val1' }];

    let newArr = arr.filter((value, index, self) =>
      index === self.findIndex((t) => (
        t.label === value.label && t.items === value.items
      ))
    );
    console.log(newArr, 'newArr');
```

Comment: Looks good now! I coudnt manage to get it to work with both `label` and `items`, but your solutions seems to do it! :)

Comment: This has _very_ low performance

Answer (score 1):

You can use hash grouping to filter by several keys:

```js
const data = [{ id: 'lAYOUT', label: 'lAYOUT', items: 'val1' }, { id: 'tecst', label: 'tecst', items: 'val1' }, { id: 'tecst', label: 'tecst', items: 'val1' }];

const unique = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const hash = `${obj.id}-${obj.label}`;
  acc[hash] = obj;
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Same result with **lodash**

```js
const data = [{ id: 'lAYOUT', label: 'lAYOUT', items: 'val1' }, { id: 'tecst', label: 'tecst', items: 'val1' }, { id: 'tecst', label: 'tecst', items: 'val1' }];

const result = _.uniqWith(data, (o1, o2) => `${o1.id}-${o1.label}` === `${o2.id}-${o2.label}`);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.js" integrity="sha512-2iwCHjuj+PmdCyvb88rMOch0UcKQxVHi/gsAml1fN3eg82IDaO/cdzzeXX4iF2VzIIes7pODE1/G0ts3QBwslA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  { id: 'id1', label: 'label1', items: 'items1' }, 
  { id: 'id2', label: 'label2', items: 'items2' },
  { id: 'id1', label: 'label1', items: 'items2' }
];

const unique = (...keys) => [
    ...new Map(data.map(item => [keys.map(key => item[key]).join(), item])).values()
];

console.log(1, unique('label'));
console.log(2, unique('label','items'));
```

Comment: Hey @Ian the problem with this solution in my case is that I need to make it unique by 2 keys: `items` AND `label`. WIth this unique function I can only make it unique only by 1 property.

Comment: Hi @Nightcorey  I misunderstood the meaning of your question, thinking that only one key is needed to distinguish, I modified my answer, now you can use multiple keys